# Correcting errors in Bibtex file

Tags: bibtex

I cannot correct an error in a .bib file (Doubleday & Co gave an incorrect placement of a tab character)
Correcting the error does nothing, even if the bib file is saved under a new name.
Is there a solution
Eoghan

Comment: Try deleting the `.bbl` and `.aux` files, and then recompile.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `&` with `\&`?

Comment: @Mico I think that's the correction the OP is referring to having made.

Comment: Deleting the .bbl and .aux files and recompiling worked fine. Many thanks Torbjoen

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.

Comment: I posed the question and I entirely agree that it is now entirely solved, by the responses. Eoghan Mac Aogáin